# Different versions of one SVG file

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg

I want to create an svg button to be used in a WordPress plugin.
Is there a way to make it compatible with a color picker to match each theme ? Maybe one file with different colors.

Comment: Hi MAGS94, welcome to GD.SE, you can change a simple svg button or image color using filters in the CSS. Do you have access to the CSS? What do you mean with "make it compatible with a color picker"?

Comment: A button is going to be used with a color picker so that it can be customized to any color within the plugin (think WordPress theme custom colors)

Comment: Don't you think this is a question you should make to Wordpress or look for an answer in this special plugin help? This is a site for graphic design questions, not for Wordpress issues.

Comment: Maybe you are right but I think this is also related to svg structure.

Comment: Ok, I repeat the first comment: you can change a simple svg button or image color using filters in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As for the svg button you could try to inject a svg symbol and use it where you need it. Then to vary the colors of the button according to the theme depends on how you have structured the plugin.

Look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeOeqM)